# What is the better way to close IOs?

Tags: java

See the codes :

I usually do like below

```
RandomAccessFile raf = null;
try {
    // do something ...
} catch (IOException e) {
    // logger
} finally {
    try {
        if (null != raf) {
            raf.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // logger
    }
}
```

Then I see I can do this in Java8

```
try (RandomAccessFile raf = ... ) {
    // do something ...
} catch (IOException e) {
    // logger
}
```

It seems a good way.

Looks like Java do the job to close IO.

---

edit 1

Personally, I like the 2nd way.

But is it good to use and has a high performance?

Comment: [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: The best way is try-with-resources

Comment: you may check only condition in finally block no need to put inner try and catch .

Comment: OK, thank you guys, I check out the `try with resources`, l have learned a lot.

Comment: @Chetan and what if `raf.close()` throws an `IOException`?

Comment: @AndyTurner if in try block any Exception is comes reference of "raf" should be nullify , in this case our condition works.

Comment: @Chetan ah, i see the point you were making.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Java 7 or higher, if the resource implements `AutoCloseable`, best practice is to use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3):

```
try (
    RandomAccessFile raf = /*construct it */
) {
    // Use it...
}
```

The resource will be closed automatically. (And yes, the `catch` and `finally` clauses are optional with try-with-resources.)

---

Regarding the code in your question:

1. Re the main `catch` block: "log and forget" is generally not best practice. Either don't catch the exception (so the caller can deal with it) or deal with it correctly.
2. In the `catch` block in your `finally` where you're closing, you're quite right not to allow that to throw (you could mask the main exception), but look at the way the spec defines try-with-resources and consider following that pattern, which includes any exception from close as a [suppressed exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed-java.lang.Throwable-).

Comment: Yes, thanks, I checked out the `try with resources`, Thanks for telling me this !

Comment: And I see that `closeable` extends `autocloseable` ....